# Hide specific column in list view based on user's membership

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, list-view, spservices

In SharePoint 2013 site, there is a custom list which has a column that should be visible to only one particular SP group.
That column will not be in forms (new/edit/disp) so I don't need hiding it from forms, just in view.
I thought of creating two views and then putting each of them in web part and adding target audiences I could do it, but I am asking if there is some better/nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance-related reasons, the SharePoint doesn't provide `column-level security` as OOTB.

**The available workarounds**

Use the below code to hide a specific column based on a specific group using SPSerevice  and JQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 $().SPServices({
 operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
 userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser(),
 async: false,
 completefunc: function(xData, Status) {

 //If the current User does belong to the group "SharePoint Group Name: HamzaQassas"
 if($(xData.responseXML).find("Group[Name='HamzaQassas']").length == 1)
 {
  // Hide the Column with its order ID in List View (Title=2 ...etc)
  $(document).ready(function(){$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide()});
 }
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

**Output**

[image]

- Use your mentioned method with multiple views in web part pages and manage `Target Audiences`
- Use a 3rd party tool like `Infowise`.

Comment: Solution 1 was what I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

Format the fields using JSLink

```
(function () {

 var ctx = {};
 ctx.Templates = {};
 ctx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Cost_x0020_Status": { "View": FieldTemplate },
  };
 };
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
    })();

function FieldTemplate(ctx) {
}
```